# NetSuite SuiteTalk "customSearchJoin" access from SOAP XML Response

Tags: c#, xml, soap, netsuite

I am still getting warmed up with NetSuite and have come across an issue I can't crack.

I am building a C# function to pull information from an XML soap response from NetSuite. This XML is the result of a saved search call which contains a section that is a join titled `customSearchJoin` that I am unsure how to access. Below I will show the XML section and my attempts to access it in the C# function.

I am attempting to access the field with the value of **091736418**

**XML segment:**

```
    <platformCore:searchRow xsi:type="tranSales:TransactionSearchRow" xmlns:tranSales="urn:sales_2014_1.transactions.webservices.netsuite.com">
    <tranSales:basic xmlns:platformCommon="urn:common_2014_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">
        <platformCommon:dateCreated>
            <platformCore:searchValue>2015-12-17T08:43:00.000-08:00</platformCore:searchValue>
        </platformCommon:dateCreated>
        <platformCommon:entity>
            <platformCore:searchValue internalId="615"/>
        </platformCommon:entity>
    </tranSales:basic>
    <tranSales:customerMainJoin xmlns:platformCommon="urn:common_2014_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">
        <platformCommon:altName>
            <platformCore:searchValue>Some Specific Customer</platformCore:searchValue>
        </platformCommon:altName>
    </tranSales:customerMainJoin>
    <tranSales:itemJoin xmlns:platformCommon="urn:common_2014_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">
        <platformCommon:itemId>
            <platformCore:searchValue>Some Product</platformCore:searchValue>
        </platformCommon:itemId>
    </tranSales:itemJoin>
    <tranSales:customSearchJoin xmlns:platformCommon="urn:common_2014_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">
        <platformCommon:customizationRef internalId="167" scriptId="custrecord_itmfulfillmentid"/>
        <platformCommon:searchRowBasic xsi:type="platformCommon:CustomRecordSearchRowBasic">
            <platformCommon:recType internalId="25"/>
            <platformCommon:customFieldList>
                <platformCore:customField xsi:type="platformCore:SearchColumnStringCustomField" scriptId="custrecord_ssccbarcode" internalId="169">
                    <platformCore:searchValue>091736418</platformCore:searchValue>
                </platformCore:customField>
            </platformCommon:customFieldList>
        </platformCommon:searchRowBasic>
    </tranSales:customSearchJoin>
</platformCore:searchRow>
```

**C# function:**

```
    private void testCustomJoinSearch() {

    TransactionSearchAdvanced transSearchAdv = new TransactionSearchAdvanced
    {
        savedSearchScriptId = "customsearch_savedSearchID"
    };

    SearchResult searchResult = _service.search(transSearchAdv);

                if (searchResult.status.isSuccess)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Search Success");

                    foreach (TransactionSearchRow transSearchRow in searchResult.searchRowList)
                    {

                        // declare vars
                        string transInternalID = "";
                        string ssccBarcode = "";

                        //normal field
                        transInternalID = transSearchRow.basic. internalId[0].searchValue.internalId.ToString();

                        //joined and custom field ? Not sure this loop is correct
                        foreach (CustomSearchRowBasic customBasicSearchRow in transSearchRow.customSearchJoin)
                        {
                                        // ????

                        };

                        Console.WriteLine("transInternalID {0}", transInternalID);
                        Console.WriteLine("ssccBarcode {0}", ssccBarcode);
                    } // end main search row
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Search Failure");
                    Console.WriteLine(searchResult.status.statusDetail);
                }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try xml linq.  I fixed your xml that was missing some namespace definitions so I added root and then closed the end tags platformCore:searchRow and root.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication70
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml =
                "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?>" +
                "<Root xmlns:platformCore=\"abc\" xmlns:xsi=\"def\">" +
                "<platformCore:searchRow xsi:type=\"tranSales:TransactionSearchRow\" xmlns:tranSales=\"urn:sales_2014_1.transactions.webservices.netsuite.com\">" +
                "<tranSales:basic xmlns:platformCommon=\"urn:common_2014_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com\">" +
                    "<platformCommon:dateCreated>" +
                        "<platformCore:searchValue>2015-12-17T08:43:00.000-08:00</platformCore:searchValue>" +
                    "</platformCommon:dateCreated>" +
                    "<platformCommon:entity>" +
                        "<platformCore:searchValue internalId=\"615\"/>" +
                    "</platformCommon:entity>" +
                "</tranSales:basic>" +
                "<tranSales:customerMainJoin xmlns:platformCommon=\"urn:common_2014_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com\">" +
                    "<platformCommon:altName>" +
                        "<platformCore:searchValue>Some Specific Customer</platformCore:searchValue>" +
                    "</platformCommon:altName>" +
                "</tranSales:customerMainJoin>" +
                "<tranSales:itemJoin xmlns:platformCommon=\"urn:common_2014_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com\">" +
                    "<platformCommon:itemId>" +
                        "<platformCore:searchValue>Some Product</platformCore:searchValue>" +
                    "</platformCommon:itemId>" +
                "</tranSales:itemJoin>" +
                "<tranSales:customSearchJoin xmlns:platformCommon=\"urn:common_2014_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com\">" +
                    "<platformCommon:customizationRef internalId=\"167\" scriptId=\"custrecord_itmfulfillmentid\"/>" +
                    "<platformCommon:searchRowBasic xsi:type=\"platformCommon:CustomRecordSearchRowBasic\">" +
                        "<platformCommon:recType internalId=\"25\"/>" +
                        "<platformCommon:customFieldList>" +
                            "<platformCore:customField xsi:type=\"platformCore:SearchColumnStringCustomField\" scriptId=\"custrecord_ssccbarcode\" internalId=\"169\">" +
                                "<platformCore:searchValue>091736418</platformCore:searchValue>" +
                            "</platformCore:customField>" +
                        "</platformCommon:customFieldList>" +
                    "</platformCommon:searchRowBasic>" +
                "</tranSales:customSearchJoin>" +
                "</platformCore:searchRow>" +
                "</Root>";

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

            string searchvalue = doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "customSearchJoin")
                .Descendants().Where(y => y.Name.LocalName == "searchValue").Select(z => (string)z).FirstOrDefault();

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is something like this:

```
foreach (CustomSearchRowBasic customBasicSearchRow in transSearchRow.customSearchJoin) {
    // ????

    CustomRecordSearchRowBasic itmfulfillmentidRecord = customBasicSearchRow.searchRowBasic as CustomRecordSearchRowBasic;
    foreach(SearchColumnCustomField customField in itmfulfillmentidRecord.customFieldList) {
        if (customField.scriptId == "custrecord_ssccbarcode") {
            SearchColumnStringCustomField stringField = customField as SearchColumnStringCustomField;

            string itmfulfillmentid = stringField.searchValue;
        }
    }
}
```